# Существует SQL запрос который выведет count число строк в дате каждой?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

Такой запрос используется для статистики, которую может показать PMA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой запрос с группировкой по дате:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`, COUNT(*) AS `count`
FROM tablename
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `date`;
```

Comment: Вы специально хотите заставить сервер пыхтеть, выполняя нафиг никому не нужную работу? Вот зачем преобразовывать дату в **строку** перед группировкой? Если поле `date` хранит только дату - группировать надо непосредственно по нему, а если  там DATETIME или TIMESTAMP - то хотя бы по ```DATE(`date`)```. А вот при отдаче результата можно и в строку преобразовать. Во-первых, количество преобразований куда как меньше, во-вторых, по сравнению со скоростью отдачи время на преобразование пренебрежимо мало.